# C# Opening PDF in Webbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, webbrowser-control

i know this question seems simple but it is giving me a headache.
I have a programm from where i want to show a pdf and this works fine and dandy
but when i want to change the pdf it won't work.
The application has two two tabpages, one for the PDF and one for the design etc.
I can click on Print and a pdf is created and it loads.
When changing the pdf, because i changed something in the first tab, it doesn't delete the old one and it won't load the new pdf file.

Here is my code:

```
//The PdfFile variable is the path to the old pdf file
//and file variable is the path to the new pdf file
if (wbPdfViewer != null)
{
    wbPdfViewer.AllowNavigation = true;
    wbPdfViewer.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.de")); //this should navigate
    wbPdfViewer.Url = new Uri("http://www.google.de"); //this is just a try 
    bool isallowed = wbPdfViewer.AllowNavigation; //check during debbuging if it is set
    string url = wbPdfViewer.Url.ToString(); //see if it works during debbuging
}

if (pdfViewer.Document != null) //this is an optional viewer ... nevermind that
{
    pdfViewer.Document.Close();
    pdfViewer.Document.Dispose();
}

try
{
    DHIO.File.Delete(PdfFile);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    #if DEBUG
      MessageBox.Show("PdfViewer 02002: Couldn't delete PDF file");
    #endif
}

if (wbPdfViewer != null)
{
    GC.Collect();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file) || !DHIO.File.Exists(file))
        return;

    wbPdfViewer.Navigate(new Uri(file));
    ShowNavigationControls();
    return;
}
```

As you can see i want to delete the PdfFile and it shouldn't be in access because i changed the page (in a later version google.de is replaced with about:blank or something else).

So my question is how to change the URL so that my program isn't accessing the pdf file anymore ?
i tried it with the navigationComplete event but this won't fire

and as always thanks in advance

Comment: I forgot to mention that the PDF opens in Adobe Acrobat Reader.

Comment: When you're navigating away from the PDF to www.google.de, the navigation doesn't happen immediately. Wait for [Navigated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx) event before trying to delete the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `wbPdfViewer.Url` to `null`.

Comment: This hasn't worked. The URL is still set to the pdf in my temp directory